# Обучение java

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Неплохо знаю синтаксис, ООП, что учить дальше - библиотеку классов, базы данных или swing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

не льстите себе. ООП вы, судя по всему, знаете так себе. Иначе подобных вопросов бы не задавали. А знание синтаксиса - вообще капля в море. Лучше попробуйте написать какое-нибудь 
приложение, попробуйте его грамотно спроектировать (заодно  задействуете и улучшите свое знание ООП), вместе с тем сможете изучить и библиотеку классов, и swing, и базы данных, и все, что угодно помимо этого, в зависимости от вашего приложения. 
 А вообще в первую очередь учите то, что не зависит от конкретного языка (даже если он вам очень нравится). А именно, алгоритмы, то же ООП, паттерны проектирования, принципы рефакторинга

Comment: в дополнение: по моему мнению не стоит тратить время на Swing, десктопные приложения -- не конёк Java.

Comment: А что конёк Java? Web? Mobile? Просто интересно Ваше мнение.

Comment: @Kerins_Sataier: Mobile, бэкенды на J2EE. Веб, как мне кажется, в меньшей степени, хотя тут я, возможно, и ошибаюсь.

Comment: Java в вебе на высоконагружеемых проектах еще как себя оправдывает.

Comment: Есть немало desktop приложений на java которые довольно неплохо себя зарекомендовали. Так что не стоит отбрасывать этот раздел как ненужный, тем более что из платформенного аналогов нет стоящих.

Answer (score 4):

При трудоустройстве в люблю более-менее серьезную компанию у кандидата на собеседовании в основном проверяют знания паттернов и анти-паттернов, также не лишними будут навыки тестирования ПО. Будь то юнит-тесты, интегрированные или нагрузочные тесты.

Такие вещи как синтаксис со временем просто входят в привычку, а умение работать с базами данных, знание библиотек, swing-ов, awt и прочего приходят с опытом, но суперважными они не являются.

Если мы говорим о Java, то неплохо бы еще знать о том, как работает сама JVM, как организовывается работа с памятью, потоками и проч. плюшками)